# If $f'(x)=A$, find $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+2h)-f(x)}{h}$

Tags: limits, derivatives

I'm stuck assuming that since by definition $f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+2h)-f(x)}{h}$ will still just be $A$, as the change in $h$ will be negligible since its heading towards $0$. Is there something I'm missing or not considering here?

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{h\to 0}$?

Comment: Is it lim h->0 instead of x->h?

Comment: yes i meant $h \rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are missing this:

$$\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x)}{h}=2\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x)}{2h}$$

Comment: Oh so would that really mean that $f'(x)$ is just going to $\frac{A}{2}$? or do i have it backwards and its going instead to $2A$ since the numerator would be larger?

Comment: @Barth You've been told $f'(x)=A$, so the limit you've been asked to evaluate is $2A$. Defining $k=2h$ might make this easier to see.

Answer (score 1):

The quantities $h$ and $2h$ go to zero at different rates as $h\to0$. So they are not negligible in the same way.

Think about the special case when $f(x)=x$. Then one limit gives $1$ and the other $2$. They are not the same.

To follow the hint in another answer, observe that
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}2\cdot \frac{f(x+2h)-f(x)}{2h}
=\lim_{t\to 0}2\cdot \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}=2f'(x)\;\;.
$$

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't think about making the substitution for 2h. thank you.